# On Prime and Maximal Ideals in a Commutative Ring with Unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1 \neq 0$, $I$ and $P$ are ideals of $R$. If $P$ is prime and $I \cap P \neq 0$, does it follows that either $I \subseteq P$ or $I$ is also a prime ideal incomparable to $P$? Does it also extend over the case where $P$ is maximal?

Comment: If $P$ is a prime but not maximal and $M$ is a maximal ideal which contains $P$, then $M\cap P\neq 0$ but both conditions does not hold.

Comment: @tetori what about the case where $M$ is not a maximal ideal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ring $\mathbb{Z}$ already has counterexamples - for instance consider $P=(2)$ and $I=(15)$, we have $I\cap P=(30)$ and $P$ is maximal, but $I\not\subseteq P$ and $I$ is not a prime ideal.

Comment: what's the part that makes it a counterexample?

Comment: I made a typo, I meant to say $I\not\subseteq P$. Therefore it satisfies neither of the two possible conditions you specified.

Comment: awwwww.. thanks a lot @curious!